# MCC21 FCR Display Closeup or Hi-res

Tags: nasa, software, design

I've been looking for close up or hi-res photos of the newer displays of the MCC21 (Mission Control Center - 21st Century) FCR (Flight Control Room), where the text is legible.

I haven't found any on Google Images.

Below is an older generation display, photographed by NASA.  This example has legible text on the flight control display.

[image]

And here is the MCC21 display, but low resolution.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: This is basically asking us to do a web search for you. How about [these](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=nasa+fcr&hl=en&tbm=isch&tbs=isz:lt,islt:10mp)?

Answer (score 6):

Online pictures of rooms new configuration are actually quite rare at the moment, especially close-ups. It's also a bit difficult to state which FCR is depicted.

Johnson Space Center (JSC) has [5 FCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_C._Kraft_Jr._Mission_Control_Center), which roles have evolved and still do. The Shuttle and the ISS FCR once have used to be controlled respectively from the [White](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_C._Kraft_Jr._Mission_Control_Center#White_FCR_.281998.E2.80.932011.29) and [Blue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christopher_C._Kraft_Jr._Mission_Control_Center#Blue_FCR_.281998.E2.80.932006.29) FCR, but ISS control has switched to FCR1, and White and Blue FCR are converted to MCC-21.

[image]
(Source: [Nasa, Mike Scott](http://home.earthlink.net/~mike_scott/JSC-Mission%20Control%20Center.pdf))

'Houston' is not the only location for ISS-related activities:

- US launches from KSC [p
  Pad-39](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kennedy_Space_Center_Launch_Complex_39) are controlled from KSC [LCC](http://enterfiringroom.ksc.nasa.gov/tour.htm).
- Russian launches from [Site-1/Gagarinskiy](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/baikonur_r7_1.html) are controlled from [TsNIImash](http://www.mcc.rsa.ru/English/osn_upr_ka.htm).
- European launches from [Kourou](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Launchers/Europe_s_Spaceport/Europe_s_Spaceport2) are controlled from the [Jupiter](http://msg-3launchcampaign.blogspot.fr/2012/06/dress-rehearsal.html) room.
- The [Russian segment](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/iss_russia.html) of the ISS is now controlled from [TsNIImash](http://www.mcc.rsa.ru/English/osn_upr_ka.htm) MCC too.
- ATV activities are controlled from in [ATV-CC](http://www.cnes.fr/web/CNES-en/6361-controlling-the-atv-from-toulouse.php) in France.

That means control centers must be interlocked to work on activities such the ISS missions. More on MCCs [here](http://www.quora.com/How-do-mission-control-centers-work).

Orion [EFT-1](http://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/files/eft1_mcc_staffing.pdf) was an opportunity to discover a part of MCC-21. Unfortunately no image displays a legible content, as you already stated. The best I could find:

[image]
[[Large image]](https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B1zq0JfIUAElpZn.jpg:large).
(Source: [Twitter / SpaceShuttleAlmanac](https://twitter.com/ShuttleAlmanac/status/530557040230690817/photo/1))

[image]
[[Large image]](https://i.warosu.org/data/sci/img/0065/67/1401692389329.jpg).
(Source: [Warosu.org](https://warosu.org/sci/thread/6567899))

[image]
[[Large image]](http://bgbwp.malibulist.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/NASA-070.jpg).
(Source: [BobGreenberger.com](http://www.bobgreenberger.com/index.php/2013/07/02/feeling-like-a-vip-at-nasa/))

[image]
[[Large image]](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-cRYtbgII-hQ/Urh8NTrWywI/AAAAAAAAJeI/zY-iNeWeGV4/s1600/2013-12-08+10.35.03.jpg).
(Source: [OhSnapLizzie.com](http://www.ohsnaplizzie.com/2013/12/houston-citypass-adventure-1.html))

[TidalWave](https://space.stackexchange.com/users/49/tildalwave) provides this link to [ISS MCC](http://spacestationlive.jsc.nasa.gov/displays/index.html) consoles. This is a live content, definitely invaluable. As an example, the [CMG system](http://spacestationlive.nasa.gov/educators/Physics-MC-ADCO-MC.pdf) view, providing CMG status and active momentum.

[image]

(Thanks for the idea!)

Comment: Nice, thanks for a thorough answer to a vague question! Thinking of it, you might wanna also add links to console displays on [International Space Station Live!](http://spacestationlive.jsc.nasa.gov/displays/index.html) and perhaps also [DSN Now](http://eyes.nasa.gov/dsn/dsn.html), [SDO Sun Now](http://sdo.gsfc.nasa.gov/data/), [NASA TV](http://www.nasa.gov/multimedia/nasatv/), [ISS cam streams](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/live-iss-stream) and [ISS HD Earth Viewing Experiment](http://www.ustream.tv/channel/iss-hdev-payload) or similar that would also regularly display on some FCR monitors.

Comment: @TildalWave: Thanks for the links. I have included the Live MCC (btw, I was not aware of the availability of live data...) For the other links, they are good too, but I suggest to open a separate topics, related to live data and video streams. I'll open the question, and let you add the information if you will.

Comment: Oh it's fine, it was just a few suggestions. For questions like this, I'd suggest that starting a new thread in our [meta] would be the better option. Or alternatively, making it a community wiki thread. There's a few reasons for that, like that it'll likely be frequently updated and that resource requests are generally not a good fit for a Q&A (no one single best answer and such, or it's a community effort anyway).